# Which account number has the most orders? SQLdev

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Here is the code I have:

```
SELECT account_name,
    count(ordered_item),
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY account_name, ordered_item 
        ORDER BY count(ordered_item) DESC
        ) Row
FROM oe_order_lines_all ool,
    cust_accounts_all hca,
    oe_order_headers_all ooh
WHERE to_date(ooh.creation_date) BETWEEN '2015-10-01' AND '2015-10-31'
    AND ooh.flow_status_code <> 'CANCELLED'
    AND ooh.sys_document_ref = ool.sys_document_ref
    AND hca.cust_account_id = ooh.org_id
GROUP BY hca.account_name,
    ool.ordered_item
ORDER BY ool.ordered_item DESC
```

I keep getting the error "FROM keyword not found where expected". I am unsure what is wrong with my syntax. I am trying to see which account (there are multiple with the same name, ie Amazon) has the most ordered items. Is there another way to find this information? What is the error in my code?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Learn how to use explicit join syntax. Aaron Bertrand did some [**writting**](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I will learn more about how to join tables properly. Sadly, the join is not an issue here.

Comment: Replace `Row` with some other name (can be "ROW" within quotes). `ROW` is reserved keyword in Oracle.

Comment: I have changed it to "ROW" and am getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem is that `ROW` is [a reserved word](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_keywd001.htm#SQLRF55621). If you change that column alias to something else that error will go away.

But you probably want a subquery to get the count for each account name, and then apply the analytic function to the result of that - without the `PARTITION BY` clause which would rank everything the same:

```
SELECT account_name, ordered_items,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      ORDER BY ordered_items DESC
      ) rn
FROM (
  SELECT hca.account_name,
    count(ordered_item) ordered_items
  FROM oe_order_headers_all ooh
  JOIN oe_order_lines_all ool
  ON ooh.sys_document_ref = ool.sys_document_ref
  JOIN cust_accounts_all hca
  ON hca.cust_account_id = ooh.org_id
  WHERE to_date(ooh.creation_date) BETWEEN DATE '2015-10-01' AND DATE '2015-10-31'
  AND ooh.flow_status_code <> 'CANCELLED'
  GROUP BY hca.account_name
)
ORDER BY rn DESC;
```

And if you only want the one with the highest count you can have a further level:

```
SELECT account_name, ordered_items
FROM (
  SELECT account_name, ordered_items,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY ordered_items DESC
        ) rn
  FROM (
    SELECT hca.account_name,
      count(ordered_item) ordered_items
    FROM oe_order_headers_all ooh
    JOIN oe_order_lines_all ool
    ON ooh.sys_document_ref = ool.sys_document_ref
    JOIN cust_accounts_all hca
    ON hca.cust_account_id = ooh.org_id
    WHERE to_date(ooh.creation_date) BETWEEN DATE '2015-10-01' AND DATE '2015-10-31'
    AND ooh.flow_status_code <> 'CANCELLED'
    GROUP BY hca.account_name
  )
)
WHERE rn = 1;
```

But `ROW_NUMBER()` may not be appropriate here. You haven't specified what should happen if two accounts have the same count. If you want to only show one of them you need a way to choose which to use, which you could do by adding a tie-braker to the function's `ORDER BY` clause. If you want to show both then use `RANK()` instead.

(I've also switched to ANSI joins; and used date literals so you aren't relying on NLS settings.)

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/23649/1).

Comment: I tought on that one too, but in sqlfiddle didnt say anything

Comment: Even after renaming, I am still getting the same error. I also tried adding quotes and it did not work as well.

Comment: What did you rename it to?

Comment: Your original query works with `"ROW"` - [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/23649/2). Only other change is adding the `DATE` keywords.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need perform a subquery

```
SELECT  account_name,
        ordered_item, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Total DESC) as rn
FROM (
     SELECT hca.account_name,
            ool.ordered_item, 
            COUNT(*) as total
     FROM oe_order_lines_all ool 
     JOIN oe_order_headers_all ooh
       ON ooh.sys_document_ref = ool.sys_document_ref    
     JOIN cust_accounts_all hca 
       ON hca.cust_account_id = ooh.org_id
     WHERE to_date(ooh.creation_date) BETWEEN '2015-10-01' AND '2015-10-31'
       AND ooh.flow_status_code <> 'CANCELLED'    
     GROUP BY 
           hca.account_name,
           ool.ordered_item
   ) T
ORDER BY ordered_item DESC
```